# Navigation Drawer On Button Click

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, drawer

I want to have a navigation drawer in my app

I have already make this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="#7e7e7e" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/sitesWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.07" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFDFE"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/webviewBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/imageview_selector"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/webviewForward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/webviewBack"
            android:background="@drawable/imageview_selector"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_forward" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mDrawerToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/imageview_selector"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and i want to use this image button

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mDrawerToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/imageview_selector"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer" />
```

to be able open the navigation drawer when it's click

I make the fragment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.webviewBack:
            isWebViewCanGoBack();
            break;
        case R.id.webviewForward:
            if (webView.canGoForward())
                webView.goForward();
            break;
        case R.id.webviewReload:
            String url = webView.getUrl();
            LoadWebViewUrl(url);
            break;
        case R.id.webviewClose:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.mDrawerToggle:
            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mDrawerToggle);
            final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mDrawerToggle);
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            return false;
    }
}
```

but i'll get error

```
error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
```

does anyone know how to fix it? 
what i want is when the imagebutton`(mDrawerToggle)` is clicked it'll open navigation drawer

thanks

Comment: you can write getApplicationContext() or getParentActivity() instead of getActivity().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write findViewById in fragment to find activity xml views.Instead try this

In you activity make this private memeber virailbe

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout,drawer;
```

Then in `onCreate` find your drawer using `findViewById`.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.mDrawerToggle);
drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.mDrawerToggle);
```

Make a method to get the reference of DrawerLayout in your activity

```
 public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout(){
   return mDrawerLayout; 
   }

 public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout(){
   return drawer; 
   }
```

And in your fragment call your activity method like this

```
DrawerLayout drawer=((YOURACTIVITY)getActivity()).getDrawerLayout();
```

Comment: In fragment you should get it,posy your fragment code also

Comment: finally it's work, but when i click the button, the navigation drawer show with blank menu? how to add the menu list view item?